# I want to center text a little bit, but it jumps to a new line

Tags: html, css

I want to center text a little bit, but after I add even **1px** of **padding-left** it jumps to a new line. I have 2 columns both take up **50% width** of the screen, in 1 column is just photo, in 2 background color and text that I want to center.

This is my CSS:

```css
.reviews__content {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-left:
}
```

Comment: Please post all the relevant html code and css

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly. And https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks as well.

Comment: https://codepen.io/ValerijMorra/pen/ZdMpEo I guess this would help.

Comment: Code relevant to your question belongs directly _into_ your question, not just dumped on an external site. (But please don’t put the whole code from the codepen into your question now - again, [mre])

Answer (score 1):

add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your code. this will help you to add padding without breaking it

```css
.reviews__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="reviews__content">
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg" />
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `width: calc(50% - 2px);` on your *reviews__content* class.

I think this solves your problem.

Comment: sadly , it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that with the following code:

```css
.reviews__content {
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-top: 170px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: [Irin's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56906084/3536236) is the correct way to solve this problem.